# Why would nameservers not be resolving even though they're listed correctly in the whois lookup?

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I cannot connect to the Tullamore Toastmasters website.

A DiG request for A records or NS records returns none. (Requests shown below.) However, a WHOIS lookup does list nameservers. And DiG requests sent directly to those nameservers *do*
resolve as expected. So somehow those nameservers are not being checked, even though they are listed in the WHOIS response. What could be going on here?

The domain was working correctly about a month ago, and then suddenly stopped, for no reason that I can think of.

```
trig@trig:~$ dig tullamoretoastmasters.org a

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-rpz2+rl.13214.22-P2-Ubuntu-1:9.9.3.dfsg.P2-4ubuntu1 <<>> tullamoretoastmasters.org a
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 40050
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tullamoretoastmasters.org. IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
org.            50  IN  SOA a0.org.afilias-nst.info. noc.afilias-nst.info. 2010795773 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 90 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 30 22:54:36 GMT 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117

trig@trig:~$ dig tullamoretoastmasters.org ns

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-rpz2+rl.13214.22-P2-Ubuntu-1:9.9.3.dfsg.P2-4ubuntu1 <<>> tullamoretoastmasters.org ns
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 24884
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tullamoretoastmasters.org. IN  NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
org.            47  IN  SOA a0.org.afilias-nst.info. noc.afilias-nst.info. 2010795773 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 85 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 30 22:54:39 GMT 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117

trig@trig:~$ whois tullamoretoastmasters.org
Access to .ORG WHOIS information is provided to assist persons in 
determining the contents of a domain name registration record in the 
Public Interest Registry registry database. The data in this record is provided by 
Public Interest Registry for informational purposes only, and Public Interest Registry does not 
guarantee its accuracy.  This service is intended only for query-based 
access. You agree that you will use this data only for lawful purposes 
and that, under no circumstances will you use this data to: (a) allow, 
enable, or otherwise support the transmission by e-mail, telephone, or 
facsimile of mass unsolicited, commercial advertising or solicitations 
to entities other than the data recipient's own existing customers; or 
(b) enable high volume, automated, electronic processes that send 
queries or data to the systems of Registry Operator, a Registrar, or 
Afilias except as reasonably necessary to register domain names or 
modify existing registrations. All rights reserved. Public Interest Registry reserves 
the right to modify these terms at any time. By submitting this query, 
you agree to abide by this policy. 

Domain ID:D163285005-LROR
Domain Name:TULLAMORETOASTMASTERS.ORG
Created On:11-Sep-2011 04:20:33 UTC
Last Updated On:26-Oct-2013 23:00:20 UTC
Expiration Date:11-Sep-2014 04:20:33 UTC
Sponsoring Registrar:Blacknight Internet Solutions Ltd. (R1806-LROR)
Status:CLIENT TRANSFER PROHIBITED
Status:HOLD
Status:PENDINGDELETE
Registrant ID:BK-33567
Registrant Name:Jennifer Dillon
Registrant Street1:Ballycommon
Registrant Street2:
Registrant Street3:
Registrant City:Tullamore
Registrant State/Province:Co. Offaly
Registrant Postal Code:00000
Registrant Country:IE
Registrant Phone:+353.877608117
Registrant Phone Ext.:
Registrant FAX:
Registrant FAX Ext.:
Registrant Email:jenniferdillon@ireland.com
Admin ID:BK-33567
Admin Name:Jennifer Dillon
Admin Street1:Ballycommon
Admin Street2:
Admin Street3:
Admin City:Tullamore
Admin State/Province:Co. Offaly
Admin Postal Code:00000
Admin Country:IE
Admin Phone:+353.877608117
Admin Phone Ext.:
Admin FAX:
Admin FAX Ext.:
Admin Email:jenniferdillon@ireland.com
Tech ID:BK-33567
Tech Name:Jennifer Dillon
Tech Street1:Ballycommon
Tech Street2:
Tech Street3:
Tech City:Tullamore
Tech State/Province:Co. Offaly
Tech Postal Code:00000
Tech Country:IE
Tech Phone:+353.877608117
Tech Phone Ext.:
Tech FAX:
Tech FAX Ext.:
Tech Email:jenniferdillon@ireland.com
Name Server:NS1.YOURDOTSER.COM
Name Server:NS2.YOURDOTSER.COM
Name Server: 
Name Server: 
Name Server: 
Name Server: 
Name Server: 
Name Server: 
Name Server: 
Name Server: 
Name Server: 
Name Server: 
Name Server: 
DNSSEC:Unsigned


trig@trig:~$ dig tullamoretoastmasters.org a @ns1.yourdotser.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-rpz2+rl.13214.22-P2-Ubuntu-1:9.9.3.dfsg.P2-4ubuntu1 <<>> tullamoretoastmasters.org a @ns1.yourdotser.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29954
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tullamoretoastmasters.org. IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
tullamoretoastmasters.org. 86400 IN A   79.140.130.6

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
tullamoretoastmasters.org. 86400 IN NS  ns2.tullamoretoastmasters.org.
tullamoretoastmasters.org. 86400 IN NS  ns1.tullamoretoastmasters.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.tullamoretoastmasters.org. 86400 IN A   79.140.130.4
ns2.tullamoretoastmasters.org. 86400 IN A   79.140.130.5

;; Query time: 79 msec
;; SERVER: 79.140.130.4#53(79.140.130.4)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 30 22:54:52 GMT 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 138

trig@trig:~$ dig tullamoretoastmasters.org a @ns2.yourdotser.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-rpz2+rl.13214.22-P2-Ubuntu-1:9.9.3.dfsg.P2-4ubuntu1 <<>> tullamoretoastmasters.org a @ns2.yourdotser.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18957
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tullamoretoastmasters.org. IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
tullamoretoastmasters.org. 86400 IN A   79.140.130.6

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
tullamoretoastmasters.org. 86400 IN NS  ns2.tullamoretoastmasters.org.
tullamoretoastmasters.org. 86400 IN NS  ns1.tullamoretoastmasters.org.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.tullamoretoastmasters.org. 86400 IN A   79.140.130.4
ns2.tullamoretoastmasters.org. 86400 IN A   79.140.130.5

;; Query time: 99 msec
;; SERVER: 79.140.130.5#53(79.140.130.5)
;; WHEN: Sat Nov 30 22:54:57 GMT 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 138
```

Comment: WHOIS information is informational. It does not have any actual bearing on name resolution for your domain. You need to contact your registrar and/or log in to their DNS control panel and set up or correct your name server information and your DNS zone. As it stands right now, your domain doesn't exist at the parent servers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to log onto your registrar site:

> $ whois  tullamoretoastmasters.org|grep NS
>   Name Server:NS1.YOURDOTSER.COM
>   Name Server:NS2.YOURDOTSER.COM

and change the above to:

> $ dig @NS2.YOURDOTSER.COM  tullamoretoastmasters.org ns +short
>   ns2.tullamoretoastmasters.org.
>   ns1.tullamoretoastmasters.org.

EDIT:

your registrar is not claiming or delegating reposonsibility for your top level domain to your name servers:

> $ dig  tullamoretoastmasters.org ns |grep AUTHORITY -A 1 
>   ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
>   
>  org.           870 IN  SOA a0.org.afilias-nst.info.
>  noc.afilias-nst.info. 2010795799 1800 900 604800 86400

the whois change, directly with your registrar, should fix it.  if your registrar and your dns hosting provider are one and the same, just call them